# How to get a certain word or number from a block of text using cheerio JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am wondering how to get all of the sets of numbers that come after "id": on each line of this link using Cheerio in JS:
https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear/products/nkcw7297-100.json

Example:

```
[{
    "id": 19437838336128,
    "product_id": 2069464547456,
    "title": "3",
    "price": "110.00",
    "sku": "12757001",
    "position": 1,
    "compare_at_price": "",
    "fulfillment_service": "manual",
    "inventory_management": "shopify",
    "option1": "3",
    "option2": null,
    "option3": null,
    "created_at": "2020-07-13T07:24:00-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2020-07-14T08:07:57-04:00",
    "taxable": true,
    "barcode": null,
    "grams": 1361,
    "image_id": null,
    "weight": 3.0,
    "weight_unit": "lb",
    "tax_code": "PC040100",
    "requires_shipping": true
  }, {
    "id": 19437838368896,
    "product_id": 2069464547456,
    "title": "3.5",
    "price": "110.00",
    "sku": "194496645118",
    "position": 2,
    "compare_at_price": "",
    "fulfillment_service": "manual",
    "inventory_management": "shopify",
    "option1": "3.5",
    "option2": null,
    "option3": null,
    "created_at": "2020-07-13T07:24:00-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2020-07-31T17:38:25-04:00",
    "taxable": true,
    "barcode": null,
    "grams": 1361,
    "image_id": null,
    "weight": 3.0,
    "weight_unit": "lb",
    "tax_code": "PC040100",
    "requires_shipping": true
  },
```

So I'd want to be able to get the 2 variants after "id": at the start of each item. (1st is 19437838336128 & second is 19437838368896 )

Answer (score 1):

You don't DOM manipulation for that. You can use `fetch` (use node.js [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch));

```
fetch('https://kith.com/collections/mens-footwear/products/nkcw7297-100.json')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {

    let variantsIds = data.product.variants.map(p => p.id);

})
.catch(console.log)
```

Comment: can u link polyfill please :)

Comment: @SalvatoreTimpani, it's there

Comment: That worked great! I got it to log all the variants, but how do I add those to a list to randomly choose a variant from?

Comment: @SalvatoreTimpani https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array

Comment: Isn't this a map not an array?

Comment: and after using that, this is what I got when I logged it:
`Random {
  _cache: {},
  _rng: RNGFunction {
    _rng: [Function: prng] {
      int32: [Function],
      quick: [Function],
      double: [Circular]
    }
  }
} undefined`

Comment: @SalvatoreTimpani, we're getting lost here. Can you ask another question?

Comment: sure I can do that

Comment: Please take a look! :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63203466/how-to-scrape-certain-text-in-a-text-block-java-script